# div input tag value changing color

Tags: css, html, input, tags

i have the following problem with that code in my html tag:

```
<div id="searchbar"><input name="searchbar" type="text" id="searchfield" value="some text" onfocus="
if(this.value==this.defaultValue) 
    this.value=''; 
    this.style.color='#11111'" 
onblur="
if(this.value=='') 
    this.value=this.defaultValue;
    this.style.color='#22222'
if(this.value==this.defaultValue) 
    this.style.color='#111111'"
```

okay, the main goal is to approve that in my searchfield where the standard value is given with "some text" should change color for only new entries.

that message "some text" will disappear on click into it. now, the new value should change its color from standard #222222 to #111111. second, when leaving this field there have to be two different ways to look at. the first possibility should be that if the new value is different from the standard one with "some text" the color should stay on #222222. second possibility would be if the new entry is the same like standard value or even no entry was made then the color should change back to the default one to #222222. so the code above works up to the last point.

if there is someone who could give me advice on how to solve that i really would appreciate. thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to use jquery! onchange and ajax to make a call that tells you if the value is a new or otherwise.

Comment: @JellyBelly, note that [jQuery is not the answer to everything](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: some more specific information would be great. thanks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Instead of your long complicated code just use HTML5 `placeholder`

[**Jsfiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/RWkyK/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="searchbar">
<input name="searchbar" type="text" id="searchfield" placeholder="Some Text" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#searchbar input {
    color: green;
}
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
}
input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
}​
```

Change the color according to your wish.

Note: [Placeholder](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp) will not support in IE.

**UPDATE**

If you wants to use a placeholder to support all browsers use this [**placeholder--a jQuery plugin**](https://github.com/danbentley/placeholder) and tweek the `style.css` in it to achieve your result.

Comment: hello, thanks for answering. using placeholder is not an option because i have a lot of ie users. even i your code is the same problem as mentioned before. here is the problem, that the color stays always to green. thanks

Comment: I'm not getting what you are really trying to achieving. As per my code, the text color will be red if there is no input(default text). But when user types the color will changes to green. This is what you need right??

Comment: i'm using firefox and the standard value comes up with green color. when typing it also will be green. afterwards it even will be green. just green.

Comment: Which version of Firefox you are using?? Also check it in Google Chrome to see the actual result.

Comment: okay, now tried safari. the colors are the right way but even in safari placeholders are not working. so there should be another way to avoid placeholders.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `:focus` **pseudoclass**

css on focus change the css as like this

**Css**

```
input[type="text"]{
color:white;
    background:red;
    padding:5px;
}




input[type="text"]:focus{
color:black;
    background:yellow;
}
```

Live demo http://jsfiddle.net/VQ99D/

More info http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/focus_pseudo_class/

Comment: hello and thanks for answering. this code has the same problem as my code. look, the problem is when typing some text the color starts with white and changes to black when typing something. after that it switches back to white. this is what i would like to avoid. here is the problem with the two different kinds of colors. if the new value is different to standard value it should change and hold color black. if it is empty or the same like standard value is should become back to white. you get it? thanks.